# Confused as to why the space of all polynomials of degree at most m is a subspace of the space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I am using "Linear Algebra Done Right" as a self study guide, and was confused by the following question in the text:

> For $m$ a nonnegative integer, let $P_m(F)$ denote the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $F$ and degree at most $m$. You should verify that $P_m(F)$ is a subspace of $P(F)$ [where $P(F)$ is the space of all polynomials with coefficients in $F$]

The book's defines degree as:

> A polynomial $p \in P(F)$ is said to have **degree** $m$ if there exists scalars $a_0, a_1,...a_m$ with $a_m \neq 0$ such that $p(z)=a_0+a_1z+...+a_mz^m$

For $P_m$ to be a subset of $P(F)$, $P_m$ must contain the additive inverse of $P(F)$, which is the polynomial with all 0 coefficients (according to the book). If my understanding of all this is correct, then isn't $P_0$, and subsequently any $P_m$, not a subspace of $P(F)$ because the definition of polynomials of degree $m$ requires at least one non-zero coefficient?

Comment: Yes, a subspace must contain the additive *identity* (not inverse). The degree of the zero polynomial isn't really something people agree on, unfortunately. So you should interpret $P_m(F)$ as "all polynomials of degree $m$ or less, and also the zero polynomial".

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistyped. Thanks, I wasn't sure if I was misunderstanding something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero vector indeed should be the polynomial with all zero coefficients. It is common to introduce the convention that this polynomial has degree $-\infty $, and thus it is included in every $P_n$.

Following the definition strictly, everything is ok. Ask yourself: is the zero polynomial excluded from $P_n$? To answer affirmatively, you will have to show that the zero polynomial has degree larger than $m$. But that is not the case!

Comment: Not so: the definition as stated does not assign any degree to the zero polynomial.

Comment: This commenter is correct, the book defines the zero polynomial's degree as he does

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, you're correct that the zero polynomial does not have a degree. But [it is conventional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial#The_degree_of_the_zero_polynomial) to think of it as having degree "$-\infty$". With this convention, then, it is in $P_m$ for each $m$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right:  the definition of **degree** you quoted does not allow for $0$ to be considered a degree-zero polynomial.  (In fact many authors adopt the convention that the degree of $0$ is actually $- \infty$.)

But the question is, what is the book's definition of "polynomial"?  You quoted the definition of *degree*, but that definition takes for granted that we already know what polynomials are, and are defining what the degree of a polynomial is.  Somewhere prior to that there ought to be a definition of "polynomial", and the definition ought to be such that every $a \in F$, including $a=0$, is a polynomial.

Comment: We may all agree that the zero function is a polynomial, but the above definition does not assign a degree to all  polynomials.

Comment: And some would even disagree that polynomials are functions. $x^2 = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, but $x^2 \neq x$ as elements of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x]$.

Comment: I am with you, @kahen.  Polynomials are one thing, polynomial functions are something else.

Comment: @vadim123 You are quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

The additive inverse of a polynomial is not the $0$ polynomial, but the negative of the original polynomial. The additive identity is the $0$ polynomial.

As $-p(x) + p(x) = 0$, and both $\pm p(x)$ are polynomials of the same degree, we see that $P_m$ does contain additive inverses.